# Cast char to short

Tags: c, casting

```
char *buffer; 
short num; 
memcpy(&num, buffer, sizeof(short));
```

`*buffer` - pointer to the buffer, where number is situated in HEX view.
I want to put this number in the variable `num` without calling `memcpy`. 
How can I do it?

```
number = (short) buffer; //DOESN'T work!
```

Comment: `number = (short) *buffer`

Comment: @Noctua: This wont take `sizeof(short)` from `buffer`, but just `sizeof(char)` and promote it to a `short`. Wont get the expected result. :)

Comment: @Noctua And what's even worse, it's UB.

Comment: It is **important** to know the endianness (the order of the bytes) in the buffer. Without that information any solution, be it your `memcpy`, the undefined cast or the byte shifting of perreal will be wrong.

Comment: @tristopia that depends on how the short got there, right?  If it were created on the platform and memcpy'd there, then you wouldn't have to worry about it, right?

Comment: In the case of `memcpy` it would be indeed not a problem. My comment was more in the context of perreal's answer which assumed a big-endian value in the buffer.

Comment: @xaxxon if it was created on the platform, how come it ended up in a character buffer? It would have been in a short to begin with! No, the fact that it's in a character buffer clearly indicated that it's pulled in from an external source, and then all bets are off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For two byte short:

```
number = (short)(
           ((unsigned char)buffer[0]) << 8 | 
           ((unsigned char)buffer[1])
          );
```

For different short:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(short); i++)
        number = (number << 8) + ((unsigned char) buffer[i]);
```

or you'll have some macros for each size.

Also, see tristopia's comment about this making assumptions about endianness.

Comment: That's going to pull in multiple bytes -- I'm not sure that's what he wants.  I guess we'd have to ask.

Comment: I think size of short is 2, so you will be reading out of the "1 byte" char :S

Comment: @xaxxon, OP has 2 bytes in memcpy so I tried to copy 2 bytes.

Comment: Oh, didn't notice xD You nailed :)

Comment: @perreal This code invokes undefined behavior, see my answer.

Comment: ***This answer is WRONG, stop upvoting it!***

Comment: @perreal The accepted answer is still wrong, yet it's getting upvoted. That's why we can't have nice things on SO...

Comment: @H2CO3, don't worry though, future readers will see all the discussion

Comment: @H2CO3 What about your answer I didn't get why I need union?? I have pointer to the input buffer. All what I want is to get first 2 bytes (if short is 2 bytes) and put it in the variable of type short

Comment: @user2439344, this one is correct now he is referring to xaxxon's answer

Comment: @perreal what if short is not 2 bytes?

Comment: @user2439344 You can't do `*(short *)buf`, because of different alignment requirements of `short *` and `char *`.

Comment: @perreal Are you sure? number = (number << 8) + ((unsigned char) buffer[i]);  number has not been initialized yet

Comment: @user2439344, I assumed it is initially 0

Comment: @perreal ok! I am not sure that it is more productive than just calling memcpy. Anyway thanks!

Comment: There's still a portability problem in your code. It supposes BIG-ENDIAN storage of the bytes in the buffer. OP's `memcpy` solution implies the same endianness for the buffer and the destination variable.

Comment: Why those casts? The `<<` promotes to at least `int` anyway.

Answer (score 4):

All answers so far suggested using `*(short *)buf`, but that's not any good - it breaks the strict aliasing rule (the alignment of `short` is greater than that of `char`, so you can't do this without invoking undefined behavior).

The short answer is: you'd be better off using `memcpy()`, but if you *really* don't want that, then you can use unions and "type punning" (note that this may result in a trap representation of the buffer of bytes which may or may not be what you want):

```
union type_pun {
    char buf[sizeof(short)];
    short s;
};

union type_pun tp;
tp.buf[0] = 0xff;
tp.buf[1] = 0xaa; // whatever, if `short' is two bytes long
printf("%hd\n", tp.s);
```

Comment: Calling memcpy for 2 bytes - is prodigally.

Comment: @user2439344 It will be optimized out, and it will make your program behave *correctly.*

Comment: This doesn't help if the source data is already in a char array, though.  You still have to load it into the union with a memcpy or somsething, right?  at which point, why not just use memcpy directly to a short.

Comment: @xaxxon Right, but still better than UB.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your memcpy of `sizeof(short)` bytes, I'm guessing you want to get the first `sizeof(short)` bytes from where buffer is pointing at.

```
number = * (short *) buffer;
```

will do that for you, as other have pointed out.

You cannot take the pointer's address and put it in a short, so you need to dereference it to get the value in the memory instead.

Comment: ***This answer is WRONG, stop upvoting it!***

Comment: Given that being able to do this is a common requirement and most people get it wrong, I wonder why there isn't a language feature 'number = interpret_as<short>(buffer)' or some such thing that does this in a safe way.

Comment: Yeah, it's only sort of wrong, except it works, right?  it's frustrating.

Comment: @trisopia But it's not the same. I don't want to copy the data anywhere, I want to say please access the data at this address as if it's a "short" and please arrange to make sure this is safe. Which in many cases won't require any actual work by the compiler. memcpy makes a copy of the data which isn't the same. I'm aware it might optimize out the copy but it's not the same thing really at all.

Comment: Ok, I was too literal with your example `'number = interpret_as<short>(buffer)'` which is perfectly translated by `memcpy(&number, buffer, sizeof (short));` but I hadn't considered it could be part of an expression.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that with "situated in HEX view" you mean the number is stored in the string like "89AB", you can use the [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) function.

```
char* end;
num = (short)strtol(buffer, &end, 16);
```

This function converts the string to a long integer. There is no corresponding function that converts to a short directly, so you'll have to do a `(short)` anyway, but that wasn't the problem, was it?

Comment: Thanks. I mentioned "put two bytes in the short variable" I am  misunderstood myself)

Comment: @user2439344 Yeah, I understood that later. Not sure what's the underlying cause of your problem though. I mean, how did the short value end up in a char* in the first place?