# Bit shifting `char` vs. `unsigned char`

Tags: c++, casting, bit-shift

I need to convert 2 bytes in `char pcm[]` to a 1 byte `short pcm_[]`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851340/cast-char-to-short) post used a C-style cast, which at first I tried out in my C++ program (using Qt):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    char pcm[2] = {0xA1, 0x12};
    qDebug()<<pcm[0]<<pcm[1];

    short pcm_ = ( pcm[1] << 8 )| pcm[0];
    qDebug()<<pcm_;

    short pcm_2 =  ((unsigned char)(pcm[1])) << 8| (unsigned char) pcm[0];
    qDebug()<<pcm_2;

    return a.exec();
}
```

I figured out that it only works if I use `unsigned char` in the bit shifting, but do not understand, why this is necessary as the input is a `char`.

Moreover, I would like to use C++-style-cast, and came up with this one:

```
short pcm_3 = (static_cast<unsigned char>(pcm[1])) << 8|
               static_cast<unsigned char>(pcm[0]);
qDebug()<<pcm_3;
```

Again, I need to use `unsigned char` instead of `char`.

So I have 2 questions:

- Is `static_cast` the right cast? In my mind is an example from somewhere that used a `reinterpret_cast`. However, the reinterpret cast does not work.
- Why do I have to use `unsigned char`?

Comment: I think you should cast to `unsigned short` or `unsigned int`. Vlad from Moscow's answer explains why it also works (thanks to the usual arithmetic conversions) if casting to `unsigned char` but I find this code rather confusing.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant only `0x12` is shifted in this code so he (perhaps accidentally) sidestepped that one

Comment: Aside: if you want an 8-bit type or a 16-bit type, you should use `uint8_t`/`int8_t` or `uint16_t`/`int16_t`. Aside #2: when you're working with bits, you should always use unsigned types unless you *really* understand the quirks that signed types.

Comment: @MattMcNabb ah, yes, you're right.

Answer (score 3):

According to the C Standard (6.5.11 Bitwise exclusive OR operator)

```
3 The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands
```

The same is written in the C++ Standard (5.13 Bitwise inclusive OR operator)

> 1 The usual arithmetic conversions are performed;

The usual arithmetic conversions include the integer promotions. This means that in this expression

```
( pcm[1] << 8 )| pcm[0];
```

operand `pcm[0]` is promoted to type `int`. If according to settings of your compiler type `char` behaves like type `signed char` then you get that value `0xA1` is promoted to signed int `0xFFFFFFA1` (provided that sizeof( int ) is equal to 4). That is the sign bit will be propogated.

Hence you will get an incorrect result. To avoid it you shoud cast type `char` to type `unsigned char` In this case the promoted value will look like `0x000000A1`. In C++ it can be written like

```
static_cast<unsigned char>( pcm[0] )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `unsigned char` because of the promotion to `int` with `operator |`

Assuming `int` is 32 bits:

- signed char `0xA1` becomes int `0xFFFFFFA1` (to keep same value)
- unsigned char `0xA1` becomes `0x000000A1`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you need to cast `char` to `unsigned char` is that `char` is allowed to be a signed data type. In this case it would be sign-extended before performing the `|`, meaning that the lower half would become negative for `char`s with the most significant bit set to `1`:

```
char c = 200;
int a = c | 0; // returns -56 on systems where char is signed
```

In this example using `static_cast` or the C cast is a matter of style. Many C++ shops stay away from C casts, because they are harder to find in the source code, while `static_cast`s are much easier to spot.

Answer (score 0):

1. You shall cast data type to unsigned, because when you "expand" a signed character to signed short it's 7th bit gets replicated to bits 8-15 of the short.
   So, from `A1` which is `10100001` you get `1111111110100001`.
2. According to [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used), reinterpret_cast is the last cast you should think of.

Answer (score 0):

The problem starts here:

```
char pcm[2] = {0xA1, 0x12};
```

On your system, `char` is signed, and has a range of `-128` through `127`. You try to assign `161` to a `char`. This is out of range.

In C and C++ the result of out-of-range assignment is *implementation-defined*. Usually, the compiler decides to go with the char with the same representation, which is `-95` .

Then you promote this to int (by virtue of using it as operand of `|`), giving the int value `-95` which has a representation starting with lots of `1` bits.

If you actually want to work with the value `161` you will need to use a data type that can hold that value, such as `unsigned char`. The simplest way is to make `pcm[]` have that type, rather than using casts.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Unfortunately I can't directly use an unsigned type, because I need this for audio recording, and the buffer (a subclass of `QIODevice`) that is used by `QAudioInput`, needs to reimplement the function `qint64 write(const char * data, qint64 maxSize)` that takes a `char`.

Comment: @user2366975 you can use `unsigned char` for your buffer, and then reinterpret-cast to `char *` when calling that function